# Se puede hacer un dropdown list que a la vez tenga input?

Tags: html, laravel

Buenas quería saber si se podía hacer un dropdown list pero que a la vez si quiero pueda ingresar un valor por teclado. Estoy usando laravel siete y este es mi dropdown.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
  <label for="account">Holding</label>
  <select name="account" id="" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Seleccione el holding de la empresa</option>
    foreach ($customers as $key => $customer)
      <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->company}}</option>
    endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

Este es mi dropdown iterado por un foreach, lo que pasa es que al principio de todo mi base de datos esta vacía es decir el dropdown se va a encontrar sin valores a elegir, por eso quiero que este la opción de agregar valores por teclado si es que no existe en el dropdown. Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: Para poder lograr eso podes usar diferentes librerías, por ejemplo "select2", acá te dejo un link de ese funcionamiento que necesitas https://select2.org/tagging

Comment: @LeonardoCabré tenes alguna otra libreria? o sabes si con bootstrap es posible?